# Pass by reference 2D dynamically allocated double array in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to convert my string into a dynamic array of doubles. Each space of my string represents a column, each ";" represents a new row. When this code runs, it only works for when *F[0][col]. When it gets to *F[1][col] it gives me the error "Unhandled exception at 0x00e4483c in CCode.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc." Anyone know why?

```
void main(void) {  
    double **F = NULL;  
    F = malloc(row * sizeof (double *));  
    for (m=0; m < row;m++) {  
        F[m] = malloc(col * sizeof(double ));
    }  
    FParser(string, &F);
for (m=0;m<rowF;m++)
    free(F[m]);
free(F);
}

void FParser(char string[256], double ***F) {  
  while (dummyChar_ptr != NULL) {
    dummyChar_ptr = strtok(dummyChar_ptr," ");
    while ((dummyChar_ptr) != NULL) {
      *F[row][col] = atof(dummyChar_ptr);
      dummyChar_ptr = strtok(NULL," ");
      col++;
    }
    col=0;
    row++;
    strcpy(dummyChar,string);
    dummyChar_ptr = strtok(dummyChar,";");
    for (x=0;x<row;x++) 
      dummyChar_ptr = strtok(NULL,";");  

  }

//example String: 1 0.1 0 0; 0 1 0 0; 0 0 1 0.1; 0 0 0 0.1
```

Comment: why don't you post complete code? we can't find definition of your row and col. Are they global variables? Maybe the problem is you shared row/col between main and FParser.

Comment: can you fix your code listing , I have think it is missing declarations and closing brace, it is hard to read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[]` has a higher precedence than unary `*` in C, so `*F[row][col]` is actually `*(F[row][col])`, and you're indexing into the wrong memory location.

Try `(*F)[row][col])`.

Incidentally, there's no reason for `FParser` to take a `double***` anyway.  `F` is already a pointer; just pass that.  The only reason you'd need to use an extra level of indirection is if `FParser` needed to modify what `main()`'s `F` points to.

Other miscellaneous bits of advice:

- Check whether `malloc` succeeded.
- Avoid global variables.
- Don't use `strcpy` unless you've checked that the source string won't overflow the destination buffer.
- The function parameter `char string[256]` doesn't actually guarantee that the input argument is an array of 256 (or more) elements, so IMO it's kind of pointless and might as well be `char* string`.

Comment: It works! Thank you, Jamesdlin, for your response and advice.

Comment: In fact, the `char string[256]` parameter *is* of type `char *` (`sizeof string` will not evaluate to `256`, for example).